# Bounded (finite-rank) Inverse Operators

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, operator-theory, pseudoinverse

While studying for my functional analysis course I encountered [bounded inverse theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_inverse_theorem) which states that given a bijective bounded linear operator $T:X\rightarrow Y$, then $T^{-1}:Y\rightarrow X$ is bounded too. (Actually at lesson it has been introduced as a corollary to open map theorem.) In particular, I was trying to relate this to finite rank operators like a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, which defines a linear map $T_A:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. Assuming such operator is bounded, I was thinking if it is reasonable asking that $T^{-1}_A x = A^{-1}x$ is bounded too in the case $m\neq n$, considering $A^{-1}$ in terms of its pseudoinverse.

Comment: All linear operators with finite-dimensional domain are bounded.

Comment: Ok, the pseudo inverse defines a new finite rank operator, thus its bounded, trivial, right. (Are there relations between the operator norms?)

Comment: It's not a matter of having finite rank (discontinuous functionals are a thing), but of having a finite-dimensional domain.

Comment: @user8354084 If you’re using the 2-norm on your Euclidean spaces, then pseudoinverses are just inverses when considering the original operator as defined on the orthogonal complement of its kernel and with codomain its range. Then you can see that the operator norm of the pseudoinverse is the inverse of the least nonzero singular value of the original matrix, while the operator norm of the original matrix is its largest singular value.

Comment: @user8354084 Since there’s in general no connection between the least and the largest singular values, I guess the only see you can say is that the operator norm of the pseudoinverse is at least the inverse of the operator norm of the original matrix (unless the original matrix is 0, of course).

Comment: @DavidGao thanks for elucidating, very helpful! (Is this topic touched in some book/paper?)

Comment: @user8354084 I’m not aware of any. I basically just stated the direct consequences of the relevant definitions.